# Lista encadeada ordenada com erros no add

Tags: java

Tenho a seguinte lista encadeada ordenada, mas estou recebendo erros no meu primeiro metodo (add). A mensagem de erro aparece em todas as 3 interações onde faco a comparacao dos valores dos nodes com o operador ">" porque o java diz que nao é um operador adequado para o tipo de argumento, sendo que o valor retornado em .getValue() é um Double. Alguma sugestão de como consertar isso para fazer a comparação normalmente?

```
//Lista genérica encadeada
public class LinkedListOrdenada<T> implements List<T> {
private Node<T> list;
private Node<T>ultimo;

public LinkedListOrdenada() {
    this.list = null;
    this.ultimo = null;
}

@Override
public void add(T obj) {

    Node<T>aux = list;
    Node<T> node = new Node();

    if((node.getValue()) < (list.getValue()) ){
       node.setNext(list);
       list = node;
    }else{
        if((node.getValue()) > (ultimo.getValue())){
            ultimo.setNext(node);
            node.setNext(null);
    }else{
        while(aux !=  ultimo){
            if((node.getValue()) > (aux.getValue()) ){
                node.setNext(Aux.getValue());
                aux.setNext(node);
                break;
            }
        aux = aux.getNext();
        }
    }
    }
}
@Override
public void set(int position, Object obj) {
    // 

}

@Override
public void remove(Object obj) {
    Node<T> node = list;

    if(node.getValue().equals(obj)){
        list = node.getNext();
        node.setNext(null);
    } else {

        while(node.getNext() != null){

            if(node.getNext().getValue().equals(obj)){
                break;
            }

            node = node.getNext();

        }

        Node aux = node.getNext();
        node.setNext(aux.getNext());
        aux.setNext(null);

    }

}

@Override
public void remove(int position) {
    Node<T> node = list;
    int i = 0;
    if(position == 0){
        list = node.getNext();
        node.setNext(null);
                }else{
    while(node.getNext()!= null) {
        if(i == position) {
            break;
        }
        i++;
        node = node.getNext();
    }

    Node aux = node.getNext();
    node.setNext(aux.getNext());
    aux.setNext(null);
}

}

@Override
public T get(int position) {
    Node<T> node = list;
    int i = 0;
    while(node != null) {
        if(i == position) {
            break;
        }
        i++;
        node = node.getNext();
    }
    return node.getValue();
}

@Override
public T first() {
    if(list!= null) {
        return (T) list.getValue();
        }
        return null;
}

@Override
public T last() {
    Node<T> node = list;
    if(node.getNext()==null) {
        return (T)node.getValue();
    }else {
    while(node.getNext()!=null) {
        node = node.getNext();
    }
    return (T) node.getValue();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean isEmpty() {
    if(list == null) {
        return true;
    }else {
    return false;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean contains(Object obj) {
    Node<T> node = list;
    while(node!= null) {
        if(node.getValue().equals(obj)) {
            return true;
        }
        node = node.getNext();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Alteracoes entre uma lista encadeada e lista encadeada circular](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/240335/alteracoes-entre-uma-lista-encadeada-e-lista-encadeada-circular)

Comment: Que erros? Todas as suas perguntas são relativas a esta lista, e em nenhuma você adicionou o erro ou a pilha de erros. Facilite a vida de quem for ajudar, não informe um erro de forma generica, adicione a pilha de erros caso estoure exceção, ou seja mais especifica sobre qual erro ocorre e como ocorre.

Comment: Especifiquei mais detalhes sobre o erro.

Comment: Para comparar os objetos genéricos é necessário usar o `compareTo` e não `>`

Comment: @Cléo Souza é preciso que você cole também aqui o código da classe Node. Mesmo supondo como é a classe Node<T> (com os atributos T value, Node next, Node previous) seu código de LinkedListOrdenada está cheio de erros (e.g. as assinaturas dos métodos overriden estão erradas, node.setNext(Aux.getValue()), faltando implementar um método de List, first() e last() não devem ter override pois não estão na interface List). Use uma IDE com visulização de erros de sintaxe para te ajudar a ver todos esses erros que precisam ser resolvidos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supondo o código da classe Node, provavelmente o getValue() de Node retorna um objeto do tipo T e não sempre um Double. Independentemente de você estar ordenando uma LinkedListOrdenada<Double> a implementação deve servir para o tipo genérico T. Além disso T deve implementar Comparable para que você possa usar o método compareTo().

Classe LinkedListOrdenada. Note a definição de <T extends Comparable> que nos permite fazer a comparação 'node.getValue().compareTo(list.getValue()) > 0'.

```
//Lista genérica encadeada
public class LinkedListOrdenada<T extends Comparable> implements List<T> {
    private Node<T> list;
    private Node<T> ultimo;

    //Seus metodos que nao devem ter @Override - first(), last()....
    //....

    // e os metodos que a interface exige
    @Override
    public int size() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean contains(Object o) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object[] toArray() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T[] toArray(T[] a) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(T e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean remove(Object o) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsAll(Collection<?> c) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends T> c) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean addAll(int index, Collection<? extends T> c) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean removeAll(Collection<?> c) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean retainAll(Collection<?> c) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public T get(int index) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public T set(int index, T element) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void add(int index, T element) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public T remove(int index) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int indexOf(Object o) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int lastIndexOf(Object o) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public ListIterator<T> listIterator() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public ListIterator<T> listIterator(int index) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public List<T> subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

Classe Node:

```
 public class Node<T> {

        private T value;
        private Node<T> next;
        private Node<T> previous;

        public Node<T> getNext() {
            return next;
        }

        public void setNext(Node<T> next) {
            this.next = next;
        }

        public Node<T> getPrevious() {
            return previous;
        }

        public void setPrevious(Node<T> previous) {
            this.previous = previous;
        }

        public T getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public void setValue(T value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }
```